# data is not passing in asp.net core

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http-post

I have problem in asp.net core which I can't figure it out.
I took a working code from asp.net MVC framework and passed it to asp.net core MVC.

The code has HTTP-POST with angular 1.6 as below

```
$http.post('/Main/Post', $scope.ContactEmailDetails, { header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
```

When I test it the `$scope.ContactEmailDetails` has the values, and debugger stops me at the beginning of the HTTP-POST method so the routing is ok.

[image: data]

```
public class ContactUsProperties
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(ContactUsProperties EmailDetails)
{
    //Working Code...
}
```

But all the data that is transferred is null,

so 2 question I have:

1. How to fix it.
2. More importantly, why?! what is the differences between ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Comment: do you have a json example for us? there might be an error in the parsing bit

Comment: Could be a model binding issue `public void Post([FromBody]ContactUsProperties EmailDetails)`

Comment: @arlanschouwstra Yes I uploaded it to here https://imgur.com/a/T80Wo52

Comment: @Nkosi As far as I know [Frombody] use to take single var (e.g string) here Iam passing an object. And lets say you are right, how come is it working on non core ASP.NET?

Comment: @saba Core is a complete rewrite of the previous version. Some things have changed from before. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Nkosi I found it irrelevant since I don't have model, also I am using angular. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @saba `ContactUsProperties` is the model being sent to the action. The fact that you say the data is null means that it is not binding the model correctly. Glad to help. Hope you find a solution. Happy coding

Comment: @Nkosi its working with [FromBody] I have no idea why, would you care to explain?

Comment: @saba in core you have to be explicit about where you are binding data from. It was included in the link I showed earlier that you said was irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

> How to fix it.

It is a model binding issue. Use `[FromBody]` attribute for the action's argument. That way the model binder know where to source the data to populate the model.

```
public void Post([FromBody]ContactUsProperties EmailDetails) {
    //...
}
```

> More importantly, why?!

Only the MS developers can tell you exactly why that change was made.

> what is the differences between ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Asp. Net Core is a complete rewrite of the previous version. Some things have changed from before.

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

> By default, model binding gets data in the form of key-value pairs
>   from the following sources in an HTTP request:
>
> 1. Form fields
> 2. The request body **(For controllers that have the [ApiController] attribute.)**
> 3. Route data
> 4. Query string parameters
> 5. Uploaded files

If the default behavior doesn't give the right results, you have to be explicit about where you are binding data from.

- `[FromQuery]` - Gets values from the query string.
- `[FromRoute]` - Gets values from route data.
- `[FromForm]` - Gets values from posted form fields.
- `[FromBody]` - Gets values from the request body.
- `[FromHeader]` - Gets values from HTTP headers.

Comment: I never managed to find a good explanation, but I saw somewhere that they wanted `[FromBody]` to be an *explicit* choice in ASP.NET Core for "security reasons". I think there's a genuine concern about a model binder approach that just grabs whatever data it can from *anywhere*.

Comment: @KirkLarkin In the same docs under sources first sentence, it will take from body automatically for `ApiController`, For MVC controllers you have to be explicit.

Comment: Yeah, that's indeed true. Adding `[ApiController]` is also an *explicit* choice.